# Updating Multiple Sheets in excel using a reference number and qualifying criteria

Tags: database, vba, excel

I have a workbook which has a masterdata sheet and sends that data to another 3 worksheets in the same book depending on criteria.

I have added a find and update function the problem I am having is that the update will only update the masterdata and I am wanting it to update all entries across the other worksheets (if that entry is in the other worksheet). Also if the criteria has changed because of the update and the the entry no longer belongs in ws2 for example but should move to ws4 to be able to do this. I am a bit stomped at how to actually implement this. Can anyone please assist.

```
Private Sub Update_Click()

Dim searchRange As Range
Dim foundCell As Range
Dim mysearch As String
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim ws4 As Worksheet
Dim TargetWorksheets As Variant

Set ws1 = Worksheets("MasterData")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("X")
Set ws3 = Worksheets("A")
Set ws4 = Worksheets("C")

mysearch = Me.Search.Value

'16 qualifying scenarios to determine where the data will be sent
    Select Case True

        Case PD.Value = "Y" And NP.Value = "Y" And Wt.Value * (1300 / 1000) >= 50 And DateValue(Me.RD.Value) - DateValue(Me.DD.Value) <= 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws2, ws3)
        Case PD.Value = "Y" And NP.Value = "Y" And Wt.Value * (1300 / 1000) >= 50 And DateValue(Me.RD.Value) - DateValue(Me.DD.Value) > 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws2, ws3)
        Case PD.Value = "Y" And NP.Value = "Y" And Wt.Value * (1300 / 1000) < 50 And DateValue(Me.RD.Value) - DateValue(Me.DD.Value) <= 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws3)
        Case PD.Value = "Y" And NP.Value = "Y" And Wt.Value * (1300 / 1000) < 50 And DateValue(Me.RD.Value) - DateValue(Me.DD.Value) > 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws4)
        Case PD.Value = "Y" And NP.Value = "N" And Wt.Value * (1300 / 1000) >= 50 And DateValue(Me.RD.Value) - DateValue(Me.DD.Value) <= 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws2, ws3)
        Case PD.Value = "Y" And NP.Value = "N" And Wt.Value * (1300 / 1000) >= 50 And DateValue(Me.RD.Value) - DateValue(Me.DD.Value) > 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws2, ws4)
        Case PD.Value = "Y" And NP.Value = "N" And Wt.Value * (1300 / 1000) < 50 And DateValue(Me.RD.Value) - DateValue(Me.DD.Value) <= 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws3)
        Case PD.Value = "Y" And NP.Value = "N" And Wt.Value * (1300 / 1000) < 50 And DateValue(Me.RD.Value) - DateValue(Me.DD.Value) > 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws4)
        Case PD.Value = "N" And NP.Value = "Y" And Wt.Value * (1300 / 1000) >= 50 And DateValue(Me.RD.Value) - DateValue(Me.DD.Value) <= 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws3)
        Case PD.Value = "N" And NP.Value = "Y" And Wt.Value * (1300 / 1000) >= 50 And DateValue(Me.RD.Value) - DateValue(Me.DD.Value) > 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws4)
        Case PD.Value = "N" And NP.Value = "Y" And Wt.Value * (1300 / 1000) < 50 And DateValue(Me.RD.Value) - DateValue(Me.DD.Value) <= 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws3)
        Case PD.Value = "N" And NP.Value = "Y" And Wt.Value * (1300 / 1000) < 50 And DateValue(Me.RD.Value) - DateValue(Me.DD.Value) > 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws4)
        Case PD.Value = "N" And NP.Value = "N" And Wt.Value * (1300 / 1000) >= 50 And DateValue(Me.RD.Value) - DateValue(Me.DD.Value) <= 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws3)
        Case PD.Value = "N" And NP.Value = "N" And Wt.Value * (1300 / 1000) >= 50 And DateValue(Me.RD.Value) - DateValue(Me.DD.Value) > 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws4)
        Case PD.Value = "N" And NP.Value = "N" And Wt.Value * (1300 / 1000) < 50 And DateValue(Me.RD.Value) - DateValue(Me.DD.Value) <= 3: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws3)
        Case PD.Value = "N" And NP.Value = "N" And Wt.Value * (1300 / 1000) < 50 And DateValue(Me.RD.Value) - DateValue(Me.DD.Value) > 1: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1, ws4)

        Case Else: TargetWorksheets = Array(ws1)

    End Select

For Each ws In TargetWorksheets

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterData")
        Set searchRange = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(what:=mysearch, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
            foundCell.Offset(0, 11).Value = Me.RD.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 17).Value = Me.DD.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 12).Value = Me.PD.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 13).Value = Me.NP.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 14).Value = Me.Brd.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 15).Value = Me.Com.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 25).Value = Me.Dt.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 20).Value = Me.PrGp.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 21).Value = Me.Iss.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 7).Value = Me.CVal.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 22).Value = Me.Un.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value = Me.Wt.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 24).Value = Me.Invd.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 26).Value = Me.Sh.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 19).Value = Me.FS.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 18).Value = Me.LN.Value
            foundCell.Offset(0, 16).Value = Me.Add.Value

    Else

         MsgBox "ID does not exist."

    End If

Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please add a [mcve]? It is very unclear what your goal is. Maybe you can add screenshots to illustrate the issue?

Comment: Adding to @Peh comments, not sure what your code is doing. You are qualifying your worksheets (which you are not using). Then you have a loop to go through all the sheets in your workbook but you are not assigning anything to them. All you are doing is assigning values back to "MasterData" sheet. Please provide an example of your sheet and what you are expecting it to look like once the code is run